# Java/Kotlin record microphone input and detect volume concurrently without distortion

Tags: java, kotlin, audio, javasound

I am creating a "Voice Recorder" app using Kotlin Multiplatform for Windows/Desktop. I got basic working functionality using the Java Sound API to record microphone input and save it to a file with the below:

```kotlin
val format = AudioFormat(41000f, 16, 1, true, false)
val targetDataLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format)
targetDataLine.open(format)
targetDataLine.start()

val audioInputStream = AudioInputStream(targetDataLine)
val outputFile = File("recording.wav")

AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, Type.WAVE, outputFile)
```

Now I'm trying to add a new feature which shows the volume of the audio being recorded to give some UI feedback. The problem is that as I attempt to add this feature, the audio recording seriously degrades. I'm mainly running into chunks of sound like it's in "fast-forward". (Please note that I'm not trained in audio particularly so I'm learning as I go).

My most recent attempt is to add in using the TarsusDSP library. I came up with this so far and it's getting better but still not the quality I'm expecting.

```kotlin
val format = AudioFormat(41000f, 16, 1, true, false)
val tarsosFormat = TarsosDSPAudioFormat(41000f, 16, 1, true, false)
val targetDataLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format)
val outputFile = File("recording.wav")
val writer = WaveformWriter(tarsosFormat, outputFile.path)
targetDataLine.open(format)
targetDataLine.start()

val audioInputStream = AudioInputStream(targetDataLine)
val jvmAudioInputStream = JVMAudioInputStream(audioInputStream)
val bufferSize = 1024

/* increasing the buffer size has lessened the 'fast forward' effect, 
 * but causes audio to get cut a bit when stopped
 */
val dispatcher = AudioDispatcher(jvmAudioInputStream, bufferSize * 32, 0)
dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(object: AudioProcessor {
   override fun process(event: AudioEvent?): Boolean {
      onVolumeLevelCaptured(event?.rms ?: 0.0) // UI function to show the volume in visual form
      return true
   }
   override fun processingFinished() {}
})
dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(writer)
dispatcher.run()
```

So my question is, how can I safely acheive extracting the volume without damaging the quality of the audio input?

Comment: I'm not up on the various libraries that are available for this right now. There is probably something that would work for you. Are you open in writing your own? One possible approach would be to extend `AudioInputStream` and make a copy of the incoming data to be used for amplitude extraction.